# I am unable to add images horizontally in my bootstrap website

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-5

i'm using bootstrap 5 and the images are not getting aligned in horizontal way. The image gets added in the lower row. i've tried everything nut it dosent's works. any help would be appriciated.
Thank you.

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<!-- Body -->
<section>
  <div class="container pt-3" class="text1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 text-center ">
        <h3> Lots of IT companies in town. Why you should choose us? </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
</section>



<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <img class="img-fluid p-2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg" width="150">
    <h4 style="font-weight: 700;">Customized requirements</h4>
    <p> Every idea is unique and that's we craft it as<br> per your requirements.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 text-center">
  <img class="img-fluid p-2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg" width="150">
  <h4 style="font-weight: 700;">Customized requirements</h4>
  <p> Every idea is unique and that's we craft it as<br> per your requirements.</p>
</div>



</section>
```

Comment: You have a space in the image src which is most likely the cause. Remove the space from the folder "our qualities", or escape it.

Comment: @sebostien according to the description the image displays. So there is no issue with the path. The sisue is the alignment of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`row` div early close

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section>
    <div class="container pt-3" class="text1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 text-center ">
                <h3> Lots of IT companies in town. Why you should choose us? </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
</section>
<div class="container" class="text1">
    <section>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <img class="img-fluid p-2" src="images/our qualities/our_qualities/customized.png" width="150">
                <h4 style="font-weight: 700;">Customized requirements</h4>
                <p> Every idea is unique and that's we craft it as<br> per your requirements.</p>
            </div> <!-- Not Here -->

            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <img class="img-fluid p-2" src="images/our qualities/our_qualities/customized.png" width="150">
                <h4 style="font-weight: 700;">Customized requirements</h4>
                <p> Every idea is unique and that's we craft it as<br> per your requirements.</p>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- Close Here -->
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explaination of your possible solution. Does everyone know have to search for changes you made?